# Sort records by array field values in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection which has documents like;

```
{
    "name": "Subject1",
    "attributes": [{
            "_id": "security_level1",
            "level": {
                "value": "100",
                "valueKey": "ABC"
            }
        }, {
            "_id": "security_score1",
            "level": {
                "value": "1000",
                "valueKey": "CDE"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Subject2",
    "attributes": [{
            "_id": "security_level1",
            "level": {
                "value": "99",
                "valueKey": "XYZ"
            }
        }, {
            "_id": "security_score1",
            "level": {
                "value": "2000",
                "valueKey": "EDF"
            }
        }
    ]
},
......
```

Each document will have so many attributes generated dynamically, can be different in size.

Is it possible to sort records based on level.value of `security_level1`? (`security_level1` is `_id` field value)

As per above example, the second document (`"name": "Subject2"`) should come first as the value (`'level.value'`) of `_id:security_level1` is `99`, which is less than of `Subject1`'s `security_level1` value (`100`) - (Ascending order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) and [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to get `security_level1` item. Then you can use [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/index.html) to convert that value to an integer so that [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) can be applied:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            level: {
                $let: {
                    vars: {
                        level_1: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$attributes", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this._id", "security_level1" ] } } } ,0] }
                    },
                    in: {
                        $toInt: "$$level_1.level.value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            level: 1
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xQv742IBLSw)

Comment: Thats a great idea. What if I need to sort by valueKey, which is a string value.

Comment: @Boat you don't need `$toInt` in that case: https://mongoplayground.net/p/fg0M6xyMptw